# What is the "Virtual Machine Host" option during the installation of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: server

[image]At the end of the procedure of installing there is an option "Virtual Machine Host" in Ubuntu 16.04, someone can explain me what is it?

Comment: I dont clearly know what you mean, a picture could clarify it. But to me it seems that's option to enable your computer to **host Virtual Machines**. If you dont enable it during the installation, you could do it later from the **BIOS**.

Comment: I've added the screenshot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC, that specific menu is based on `tasksel`, and that option is for installing the [KVM Virtual Environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)

To be able to use KVM, you will need a CPU that supports either

- Intel VT-x

or

- AMD-V

You can use the `egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo` command to find out if your CPU supports this option, and you will need to make sure it is enabled in the BIOS.